# show an existing div with drop-down button inside a clone?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a clone of a div where i have some drop-down buttons. In my original one the drop-down buttons works perfectly (you will see in the code). But in my clone the drop-down button is shown but when i clicked them i want them to work like the real one. Another thing, i wish my clone will always be displayed after the selected service list. i.e. if i choose pant, then the div of 'pant' will display and after that there will be the 'add' button, the pant div will be remain same and by pressing the 'add' button i can add more fields. i.e. i can display the 'shirt' div by selecting the 'shirt' from the clone 'select service'. I seek the result in **jquery**. TIA

```js
$(function() {
  $('#selectService').change(function() {
    $('.hidden-fields').hide();
    var $target = $(this).val();
    $('#' + $target).show();
  });
  
  //creating a clone
  // but how i add the same functionality????
  $("#add").click(function() {
     var $orderClone  = $("#orderClone:last");
     var $clone = $orderClone.clone();
     $clone.find('*').val('');
     $orderClone.after($clone);
   });
});
```

```css
.hidden-fields {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="orderClone" class="row">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>Service</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="selectService" name="service[]" class="form-controlservice">
            <option disabled="" selected="">Select Service</option>
            <option id="one" value="shirt">Shirt</option>
            <option value="pant">Pant</option>
            <option value="suit">Suit</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-fields" id="shirt">
  <h4><b>Shirt</b></h4>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-group required"> <label class="control-label">Body</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="body" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label">Shoulder</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shoulder" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label">Neck</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="neck" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-fields" id="pant">
  <h4><b>Pant</b></h4>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-group required"> <label class="control-label">Length</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="length" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label">Thigh</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="thigh" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 hidden-fields" id="suit">
  <h4><b>Suit</b></h4>
  <hr/>
  <div class="form-group required"> <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="length" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group required">
    <label class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="thigh" />
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<button type="button" id="add" name="add" class="btn btn-success" >Add</button>
```

Comment: `var $orderClone  = $("#orderClone:last");` IDs should be *unique* in a single document. You should use a class instead.

Comment: Additionally, the `.click` event is only going to bind to elements that exist at the time the script is run.  You should consider [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for your event binding.  While it's "sloppy" to bind to the document, I don't see any other parent elements to use in this example: `$(document).on('click', '#add')` <-- which, per previous comments, should be a _class_, not an _ID_ - jQuery will NOT properly work when multiple elements with the same ID exist.